# Feedback on proof of bijectivity in $F(A, B) = (X \setminus A) \cup (Y \setminus B)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> we have a Function F defined as $$\begin{align*}F \colon
>  \mathcal{P}(X) \times \mathcal{P}(Y) &\to \mathcal{P}(X \cup Y) \\ 
>  (A, B) &\mapsto F(A,B) = (X \setminus A) \cup (Y \setminus B)
>  \end{align*}$$
>
> with $X \cap Y = \emptyset$.
>
> In order to prove bijectivity we need to show that for every $C \in
>  \mathcal{P}(X \cup Y)$ there is only one corresponding pair of $(A,B)
>  \in \mathcal{P}(X) \times \mathcal{P}(Y)$ such that $F(A, B) = C$.
>
> As $X, Y$ are disjunct we can discuss all possible combinations of $x
>  \in X, y \in Y$ separately.
>
> For all given $x \in X \land x \in C$ there is only one possible $A
>  \subseteq X$ where $x \notin A$ such that $x \in X \setminus A$.*
>
> Same argument holds for every $y \in Y \land y \in C$.
>
> As there is maximum of one corresponding pair of $(A,B)$ for every $C$
>   we have satisfied the condition of infectivity and we can construct
>   $(A,B)$ so that we can make any $C$ in the image of F we also met
>   surjectivity thus the function F ist bijective.

I think I got the idea correct however I feel that the argument at * may not be very strong or detailed.

Do you agree? What else could I improve?

Comment: I think what you are essentially saying at * is: $X \cap F(A,B) = X\setminus A$. While this is true I would say you need to explain better why.

Comment: @Nex Should I show this for a elements in X?

Comment: One can prove this in many ways depending on what you know. For example one can prove it using the fact that the power set is a boolean algebra. If $B$ is a boolean algebra your identity follows from the fact that for any $a \leq x$ and $b \leq y$ in $B$, if $x \wedge y=0$, then $x \wedge ((x \wedge a^{c})\vee (y \wedge b^{c})) = x \wedge a^{c}$ (where $a^c$ and $b^c$ are the complements of $a$ and $b$).